# Need to make a Counter using enum ordinals

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I need to make a counter array for a Rock Paper Scissors game but can not figure out how to make user input call the enum, and i need to make the moves for the game a counter for them to be used and compared to.

This is my enum

```
public enum Moves {

Rock(1), 
Paper(2), 
Scissors(3), 
Lizard(4), 
Spock(5), ;


private int countOf = 0;
private int moveVal;
private ArrayList<Moves> movesList = new ArrayList<>();


Moves(int moveVal) {


}

public int getmoveVal() {
    return moveVal;
}

public int getCountOf() {

for(Moves moveList : Moves.values()) {
    countOf++;

}
    return countOf;
}
```

And this is my class that would call it

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
RockPaperScissorGame rsg = new RockPaperScissorGame(3); 
Moves move[] = Moves.values();

int playerMove = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < move.length; i++) {

}

    boolean continueGame = true;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(continueGame)
    {
        System.out.println(rsg.moveChoices());

        System.out.println("Enter Move:(1,2,3,4 or 5):");
        playerMove = keyboard.nextInt();
        rsg.playRound(move);
        System.out.printf("AI %s!%n", rsg.getAIOutcome().toString());
        System.out.printf("Player %s!%n", rsg.getPlayerOutcome().toString());

        System.out.println(rsg.moveOutcome());
        System.out.println(rsg.currentScore());


        if(rsg.isGameOver())
        {
            System.out.println(rsg.currentWinTotal());

            System.out.println("Do you want to Play Again(1 - Yes , 2 - No):");
            int answer = keyboard.nextInt();


            if(answer == 2)
            {
                continueGame = false; 
            }
            else
            {
                rsg.reset();
            }
        }           

    }
```

Comment: Why not use an `EnumMap<Moves, Integer>`? You shouldn't have mutable fields in an enum, the values are meant to be constants.

Comment: Your enum code has more `{`'s than `}`'s.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through `values` to find a `Move` matching that `moveVal`:

```
public Move fromMoveVal(int moveVal) {
  for (Move m : Move.values()) if (m.moveVal == moveVal) return m;
  return null;
}
```